# Would a commutative power operator simplify some equations of physics?

Tags: notation, mathematics

[Hypertype Theory](https://beta.observablehq.com/@ishi/introduction-to-hypertype-theory) makes the radical suggestion that a commutative power operator would be preferable to the traditional non-commutative power operator $a^b$. Are there any equations in physics that would be simplified by using such an operator?

**Non-commutative Power Operator**: $a^b = e^{\lg(a)×b}$

**Commutative Power Operator**: $a \# b = b \# a = e^{\lg(a)×\lg(b)} = a^{\lg(b)} = b^{\lg(a)}$

**Identity Element**: $a\#e = e\#a = a$

**Inverse Operator**: $a \backslash b = e^{\frac{\lg(a)}{\lg(b)}} = a^{\frac{1}{\lg(b)}}$

**Traditional Connection**: $a^b = a\#e^b$

**Terminology**:

The $\#$ operation is called *expansion* and $a \# b$ reads *“a expands b”*.

The $\backslash$ operation is called *contraction* and $a \backslash b$ reads *“a contracts b”*.

Obviously, many equations like $e = mc^2$ would suffer from such a replacement and should be left untouched. The question is interested in more complex equations that could be simplified.

**Note**: This is important because addition and multiplication are commutative, but exponentiation is not. If one thinks of a multiplication as doing multiple additions and an exponentiation as doing multiple multiplications, the lack of commutativity for exponentiation is bothersome. Instead, one should think of addition, multiplication, and expansion as being the same operation applied to different exponential scales. Obviously, the same goes for subtraction, division, and contraction.

**Algebraic Foundations**: [Hypertype Theory](https://beta.observablehq.com/@ishi/introduction-to-hypertype-theory) shows that an infinite number of such pairs of operators can be created in a recursive manner using very simple equations. The simplicity and beauty of the model suggests that we are looking at something interesting.

Comment: I guess the question is, do any equations use the expression $a^{\log b}$? I can't think of any right now.

Comment: @Javier Directly or indirectly. And there is an even more interesting underlying question: would *thinking* of a power law as a commutative operator help further our understanding of some equations? Think of the use of complex numbers as helping us to understand or construct some equations.

Comment: step 1 would be to solve the quantum hydrogen atom with this and then show that some difficult problem becomes easier else it would get 0 traction.

Comment: I can’t think of any physics equations that this concept would simplify. In physics, concepts involving exponentiation are conceptually non-commutative. To get an area, we raise a length to the second power. We do not raise 2 to the power of the length. The latter doesn’t even have meaning unless lengths are measured in dimensionless units.

Comment: @G.Smith This is odd: I always thought of an area as being the multiplication of two lengths.

Comment: We write areas as meters-squared, not meter-meters.

Comment: @G.Smith Indeed, and there is nothing wrong with it. And that is because we are using the power of 2 as a shortcut for doing the multiplication of a quantity with itself, which is fine. But exponentiation becomes useful when we are looking at expansion or contraction rates. And when we do that, I like to believe that having commutative expansion and contraction operators would be preferable.

Comment: So go find some physics equations where this concept simplifies things. Good luck.

Comment: @G.Smith I will do just that and report any positive findings if the question can be kept open. thank you for your guidance.

Comment: I'm sure you can find _some_ equations that are simplified, though I don't personally recall seeing the combination $a^{\log b}$ that often. The question is whether it comes up often enough to justify remembering another notation.

Comment: Sure, information theory is a good bet, because there are lots of logarithms and lots of dimensionless quantities. Physics a bit less so -- too many things have dimensions and wouldn't work.

Comment: @IsmaelGhalimi was not a joke.

Answer (score 3):

I think this question gets the point of notation backwards. Good notation is invented when you notice that your calculations would look nicer if you made a few new definitions. You're trying to start with a definition you like for non-practical purposes and looking for a context where it would be practical.

You will surely find *some* equations out there that are shorter with your notation, but that's true for *any* notation. I could define $\biguplus = 27$ and use that to shorten some equations. Feynman gives the example of defining $\mathscr{U} = |\mathbf{F} - m \mathbf{a}|^2$, so that Newton's second law simplifies to the "elegant" form
$$\boxed{\mathscr{U} = 0.}$$ 
As always, the benefit of the notation has to be traded against the mental overhead of "unpacking" it. For example, with differential forms we can boil down Maxwell's equations to 
$$d \star F = \star J.$$
This elegance is worth the overhead because we actually *can* compute within it; we don't have to unpack it to regular tensor notation to actually use it. But I suspect that most people who encounter your # notation will immediately unpack it to regular exponentials, because those are so much more familiar, completely negating the benefit. It's like a fancy new programming language. If you build it, they'll won't come unless it's useful.

The other roadblock, of course, is that most quantities in physics have dimensions, while your expression only makes sense if both $a$ and $b$ are dimensionless. That's why you're having more luck looking at pure math.

Comment: My proposal is not just about a different notation. It’s about a different operator. And it goes right to the core concept of commutativity, which goes far beyond the simple trick of swapping two values around an operator. The question of dimension is much more interesting though, and I am not yet convinced that my operators prevent the use of dimensional quantities. But they might help us look at dimensions under a different light. This would be especially useful for things like temperatures for example, which might explain why the first application is related to entropy.

Comment: @IsmaelGhalimi I would argue that the "core concept of commutativity" isn't that much of a core concept in modern physics, since, for example, quantum mechanics only describes the real world if some operators explicitly _don't_ commute with each other (like position and momentum, for example, or in quantum field theory, the color gauge fields of QCD). I'm also not quite sure what you mean when you say, "This would be especially useful for things like temperatures for example."

Comment: @probably_someone I am not saying that everything should commute. On the contrary. Having both commutative and non-commutative power laws is critical. Unfortunately, we’re only using the non-commutative today. For some things, this is the right power law, but for others, it prevents us from really understanding what’s going on. Switching to a commutative power law would not only make the equations much simpler, but it would improve our deep understanding of these equations. Regarding my comment on temperature, I need to do some more homework to explain things the right way.

Comment: @IsmaelGhalimi I don't see how it has been demonstrated that "having both commutative and non-commutative power laws is critical." The definition of exponentiation comes directly from group theory, where the base and the exponent _don't even have to be part of the same set_, let alone commute with each other! (In particular, the base is an element of the group, and the exponent is a member of the integers, regardless of the group of the base).

Answer (score 3):

Every operator can be symmetrized, antisymmetrized, and potentially broken down into just about any combination of internal and external group structures. For your particular case, see the BCH (Baker-Campbell-Hausdorff) formula.

The operators you put forward are wrong because $a^{\log b}$ does not equal $b^{\log a}$ unless $a$ and $b$ commute to start with. You can confirm this easily by writing out the power series for $e^{\log a \log b}$ versus $e^{\log b \log a}$.

The short answer to your question is, though, that any operator which can be linearized can be put in matrix form. From there you can simply replace powers of the operation (or transcendentals in series of powers) with functions on the sum of functions of the eigenvalues.

Comment: @thorondor:  were you unaware that $3$ and $7$ commute?